# How and where to store api response data so that i can be used whenever needed in flutter?

Tags: json, api, flutter, response

Im just trying to store the response i get somewhere but could not figure out where and how. Ive read about shared preferences but was confused about how to store json data there. Can some one please help me and explain me abouth this scenario?

Comment: You can use the `setString` method of SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how much data you have. If it isn't much, you can use SharedPreferences (json is just stored as String).

If you have alot of data, I suggest using sqflite. It is pretty simple to implement, have a look at the docs here: https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite